# How to select table dynamically from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this function in c#:

```
using (SKContext db = new SKContext())
{
    dynamic dynamic = new ExpandoObject();

    if (category == "Categories")
    {
        dynamic = db.Categories
                    .Where(X => X.Active == true)
                    .Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
    }
    else if (category == "Brands")
    {
        dynamic = db.Brands
                    .Where(X => X.Active == true)
                    .Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
    }
    else if (category == "Characters")
    {
        dynamic = db.Characters
                    .Where(X => X.Active == true)
                    .Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
    }

    return dynamic;
}
```

I would like to dynamically choose a table by string kind of like this:

```
var tableName = "Brands";
return db.[tableName].Where(X => X.Active == true).Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going dynamic I would recommend to introduce some discriminator type/interface and declare common properties/functionality there:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    bool Active { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category : ISomeInterface {...} // and others
```

And use this interface to build query:

```
IQueryable<ISomeInterface> query = category switch
    {
        "Categories" => db.Categories,
         // ...
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
    };
 return query.Where(X => X.Active == true).Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: It's good way to query. But what if I want to choose different table to add records based on some condition. i.e. based on some condition I want to add data to table1 or table2 both of which implements common interface

Comment: @Sanyam without code it is hard to tell, but I think you will need to look into generic methods with `new` constraint and/or generator factory parameter.